# How do I write a console application in Windows that would minimize to the system tray?

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++

I have a written a Visual C++ console application (i.e. subsystem:console) that prints useful diagnositic messages to the console.

However, I would like to keep the application minimized most of the time, and instead of minimizing to the taskbar, appear as a nice icon on the system tray. I would also like to restore the console when the system tray icon is clicked.

How should I change my program to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is going to be an ugly hack.

First, you have to retrieve the `hWnd` / `hInstance` of you console application. Right now, I can only come up with one way:

- Create a Guid with `CoCreateGuid()`
- Convert it to a string
- Set the title of the console window to this guid with `SetConsoleTitle()`
- Find the `hWnd` of the your window with the Guid as the tile with `FindWindow()`
- And you can do it from the usual way from this point. [See http://www.gidforums.com/t-9218.html for more info.](http://www.gidforums.com/t-9218.html)
- Don't forget the rename your console window to the original title once you're done.

As you can see, even though this is possible to do, it's a horrible and painful solution. Please don't do it. Please do not minimize console applications to the system tray. **It is not something you are supposed to be able to do in the Windows API.**

Comment: Interesting Application of a GUID :)

Answer (score 4):

You might want to write a separate gui to function as a log reader.  You will then find it much easier to make this minimize to the tray.  It would also let you do some other stuff you might find useful, such as changing which level of logging messages are visible on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

To learn the console's hWnd you have two choices:

- On Windows 2000 or later you can use the GetConsoleWindow() function. Don't forget to define _WIN32_WINNT as 0x0500 or greater before including windows.h to have access to this function.

  If you want to run your program on earlier Windows versions as well then you must use something like the GUID trick described above.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best bet is to create a ["Message-only window"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599.aspx#message_only) (a message queue without a visible window) to receive the Notification Area messages.

Answer (score 0):

The answer with a GUID is completely ridiculous  (no sense at all)
The  Console hWnd is of course given by GetConsoleWindow() (!)